# Is there a fourth way to get the audio device (IMMDevice)

Tags: windows, audio-device

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/nn-mmdeviceapi-immdevice) of windows, I know that there are three ways to get the audio device:

IMMDeviceCollection::Item
IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint
IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDevice

then I hook the three ways, And I see all of them has been called,
And I find a device been created but not by the above ways.
So how did it created with? (it is a default device)

Comment: Debug the problematic application to find out?

Comment: @Anders the application is a executable program without source code, I hook it with a dynamic library, and have tried to print call stack but still can not see the call functions

Comment: Breakpoint on CoCreateInstance?

Comment: @Anders I have debug it well, but can not see any usefull stack information

Comment: I also hooked DriectSound functions later but never been called

Comment: IMFMediaSource can create audio device?